# Accessing MongoDB in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, handlebars.js

I'm new to web programming and I want to create a profile page for registered users on my website, and I can't get how. 
Basically just the user's name and a picture he had chosen.

That's my profile.handlebars code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1><%= user.firstName + " " + user.lastName %></h1>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="<%= user.avatar %>" alt="user profile image">
            <div class="caption"><a href="mailto:<%= user.email %>"><%= user.email %></a></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        description 
    </div>
```

and this is the user.js model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

// User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String
    }
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

What happens is that the profile.handlebars code is just printing "<%= user...." as it's a string, and I want it to print the user's name that is now logged in.

These are the errors I get when opening profile.handlebars page:

```
URIError: Failed to decode param '%3C%=%20user.avatar%20%%3E'
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
    at decode_param (I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:172:12)
    at Layer.match (I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:148:15)
    at matchLayer (I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:574:18)
    at next (I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:220:15)
    at Function.handle (I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
    at next (I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (I:\Programming\Gamon2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using {{user.avatar}} and {{user.email}}

The <%= %> notation is used in JSPs for handlebar you should use curly braces {{}} around your variables.

Comment: It has worked, it does detect that it's javascript, but it's not giving the user's details, leaves it blank. Could you know why?

Comment: What do you mean by users details ?

Comment: Try {{this}} instead of {{user.avatar}} to see if you get something. If yes try to pring the user {{user}} to see if the user is get.